# How do I use jQuery's .get() method with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, express

I'm a complete MongoDB beginner and I'm wondering how jQuery's .get() method works.  I've been able to use .post() to add and update items in the DB, and that jQuery looked like this:

```
$.post(document.URL, {'answers':answer})
```

Now I'm trying to get information to the client side first using the following find() method, which successfully retrieves the correct information and logs it into terminal.

```
this.find(query, {"answers":"true", "blanks":"true"}, function(err, doc){
   console.log("The correct info appears in terminal: "+doc);  //{_id:52a52ee1e80e7c0000000001, answers: [ 'more', 'One', 'more' ],  blanks:    ['try']}

   return doc;
   callback();
});
```

Than I'm trying to send that same info to the client-side with this jquery, but it only logs the html on that page, and not the desired 2 arrays from mongo.

```
$.get(document.URL, {'answers':[], 'blanks':[]}, function( doc ) {
    console.log( doc ); //This is all the html on my page
});
```

How do I .get() the 2 arrays?

Comment: It's pretty much exactly the same, but instead of `app.post`, you'd use `app.get`, the database retrieval stays the same

Comment: I am using `app.get`. `app.get("/post/:id", function (req, res, next) {
...`